# Chrome and Firefox overflow:hidden jumping elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, overflow, css-position

I stumbled over a strange behaviour that occurs in Chrome and Firefox when you have got an element with "position:relative;" and "overflow:hidden;" and an anchor in it with "position:absolute;".

Whenever the anchor gets focus the element above it magically jumps to the top, even though its styles and markup tell a different story.

Example: http://codepen.io/mediadivisiongmbh/pen/pJWmxp

All you need is a setup similar to this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>I can fly</h1>
  <a class="focus-me" href="#">Evil Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;

    /* Optional */
    border:1px solid gray;
}

.focus-me {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Thanks for your answers so far. In order to clarify the issue please take a look at this example:

http://codepen.io/mediadivisiongmbh/pen/bdRjKy

When you hover over the container, the absolute positioned element containing the anchor will transition in view. When you click on it a lightbox (in this case Magnific Popup) is opened. After you close this lightbox the anchor gets focus again and jumps into view, which looks pretty odd.

Setting the anchor to `display:none` by default and `display:block` when hovering over the container worked for solving this issue.

Comment: Of course it jumps up, as it wants to put the thing you are selecting in focus. The browser will try to bring it into view, and it does that by moving the `p` up. `overflow:hidden` only makes sure it's not visible if it doesn't fit in the `.container`, but when you put focus on it by pressing TAB, it's being pulled into view. Also, why you would want the functionality you're trying to create, is above me.

Comment: @Rvervuurt: I have updated the question so you can see the issue in a more practical context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I figured out that the problem is caused by an accessibility feature in chrome.

In my case I just needed to make sure the anchor tag is only accessible while hovering over the container element.

Therefore the solution was altering the CSS like this:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;

    /* Optional */
    border:1px solid gray;
}

.focus-me {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

.container:hover .focus-me {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty clear about what you're looking for since you have `different story`. But if you mean you want to prevent jump because of focus on your link, you can use `tabindex="-1"` on your link to makes it not accepting tab stop. Check the [Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/mahdaen/pen/bdoPbr)

**EDIT**

Well when seeing your pen, I think you need to set `display: none` to your evil link and set it to `display: inline-block` when hovering to your container. Check [Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/mahdaen/pen/QbqXEr).

Comment: This solution works if you just want to make sure the anchor is not focused using TAB. However via javascript it is still possible to focus the element, which results in the same strange behaviour.

Comment: Yes, since I'm not pretty clear about what he wanted. hehe