# Press Tab from input shifts the input up in Chrome only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Took me sometime to replicate this in jsfiddle. But I did it:

https://jsfiddle.net/zhankezk/uvmxq6we/2/

**Steps to replicate:**

Click in search textbox, press tab key

**Issue:**

the search textbox and search button shifts up

**Expected:**

They should stay where they are.

The html here are pieces from the actual site. But I noticed that issue happens only when it's under "global-nav theme--personal" div and the reason that I feel this is a Chrome bug is because firstly, it's working fine in Firefox and IE. Secondly, after pressing tab and it shifts places, if you adjust any vertical styling, the issue will be gone, for example, you can uncheck "position:relative" for div "global-nav__search is-expanded" and tick it again. the issue would go away.

```
<div class="global-nav theme--personal">
  <div class="c-search fn_search-suggestions">
    <div class="global-nav__search is-expanded">
      <input type="search" class="search__field" placeholder="Search" name="query" data-target-url="/personal/personalsearchresults" autocomplete="off">
      <a href="#" class="icon-search fn_search-button" tabindex="-1"><span class="vh">Search</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="c-suggestions" tabindex="-1">
      <a href="#">Search for ‘home’</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can be totally wrong, thanks anyone in advance for helping!

Comment: I don't know the answer, and am too sleepy to continue debugging, but I did happen to notice that if I comment out the `overflow: hidden;` on `.global-nav .c-search`, it doesn't shift. So therein might lie a clue.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. yes it resolves the issue. However we kind of need it to hide when overflow. I really want to know why it happens. @MaxStarkenburg

Answer (score 0):

This one's weird to me, and I'm not totally sure it doesn't represent a bug in Chrome (and/or [perhaps an accessibility feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979812/)), but it seems that Chrome is

1. overflowing the large "Start" content as hidden as expected (even though it's absolutely positioned, *its* parent is relative)
2. not hiding the overflowing absolutely positioned child (as expected?) since the overflow:hidden'ed container isn't absolute/relative positioned itself, but it seems that
3. when tabbing to the absolutely positioned element's link, Chrome suddenly seems to want to take into account the content before it, including the bigger "Start" link, so it seems to be "scrolling down" the content of the overflow:hidden'ed element for you (even though what you're changing focus to is already visible because of the absolute positioning).

(At least I think that's what happening. Especially because I couldn't see any CSS properties changing in the Inspector when tabbing back and forth.)

So what to do? It seems that two workaround are to either

1. change the `line-height` property of that "Start" button to match the font-size (1.625rem), I guess so that it's height is taken into account for the overflow, and/or
2. set an explicit (and big-enough) height on the `.global-nav .c-search`, I guess so that Chrome doesn't get "surprised" by different contents' height in the `overflow:hidden` element.